# Server Error in '/' Application using asp.net in webmatrix

Tags: asp.net

im studying asp.net using webmatrix and try to run a simple program like this in Index.cshtml:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>MyWebsite</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Hello Programmers!</p>
</body></html>
```

but i got this error and i don't know why. Please help me. Thank you
[Server Error in '/' Application.

This type of page is not served.

Description: The type of page you have requested is not served because it has been explicitly forbidden.  The extension '.cshtml' may be incorrect.   Please review the URL below and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /Index.cshtml

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34009][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBkfN.png)

Comment: cshtml files are views that aren’t served out as themselves, like the error says. Use .aspx if you just want a page.

Comment: yeah its working but there is a way to run a cshtml file?

Comment: Put it into an MVC application as a view.

Comment: yet i have no idea about MVC. is there a possible way to run this code using cshtml?